# Make module asynchronous - nodejs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have the following function which I export to use somewhere else with the `async.series` method. However when I run `apiCaller._get` in my IDE's debugger, it returns `undefined` before performing the get request. The get request is executed nonetheless. However `apiCaller._get is not asynchronous and I know it needs to take a callback, however I don't understand where to call the callback.

```
var http = require("http");
var querystring = require("querystring");
var _ = require("underscore");

apiCaller = {};

apiCaller.token = null;

var server=http.createServer(function(req,res){});

server.listen(8080);

apiCaller._get = function (context, config, TheCallback) {

    // get the parameters for our querytring
    var oauthParams = _.pick(config, "client_id", "client_secret", "grant_type");

    // create the querystring
    var params = querystring.stringify(oauthParams);

    var options = {
        method: "GET",
        hostname: config.host,
        path: "/my/path/to/token?" + params,
        headers : {
            'Content-Type': "application/json",
            'Accept': "application/json"
        }
    };

    var _callback = function(response) {
        console.log('STATUS: ' + response.statusCode);
        console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(response.headers));
        var str = '';

        //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            str += chunk;
        });

        // error response
        response.on("error", function (error) {
            if ( !context ) {
                console.error("Something went wrong with the api response.");
                return;
            }
            context.done(new Error("Something went wrong with the api response."));
        });

        //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
        response.on('end', function () {

            apiCaller.token = JSON.parse(str).access_token;
            // we want to stop the request if token is not correct
            if ( !apiCaller.token || apiCaller.token === undefined || apiCaller.token === null ) {
                if ( !context ) {
                    console.error("Something went wrong with the token. Wrong token! Token: %s", apiCaller.token);
                    return;
                }
                console.error("Token: %s", apiCaller.token);
                context.done(new Error("Something went wrong with the token. Wrong token!"));
            }
            console.log(str);
            console.log(apiCaller.token);

        });
    };

    var request = http.request(options, _callback);

    request.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('problem with request');
    });

    request.end();
};
```

Comment: `apiCaller._get()` IS asynchronous because it calls a bunch of asynchronous things.  You would call the `TheCallback` from within your function when you've collected the final async result and you would pass the callback that result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass in a function as the formal parameter `TheCallback` and call it in the `end` event handler for `response` in the `_callback` function.

E.g.

```
var _callback = function(response) {
        console.log('STATUS: ' + response.statusCode);
        console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(response.headers));
        var str = '';

        //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            str += chunk;
        });

        // error response
        response.on("error", function (error) {
            if ( !context ) {
                console.error("Something went wrong with the api response.");
                return;
            }
            context.done(new Error("Something went wrong with the api response."));
        });

        //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
        response.on('end', function () {

            apiCaller.token = JSON.parse(str).access_token;
            // we want to stop the request if token is not correct
            if ( !apiCaller.token || apiCaller.token === undefined || apiCaller.token === null ) {
                if ( !context ) {
                    console.error("Something went wrong with the token. Wrong token! Token: %s", apiCaller.token);
                    return;
                }
                console.error("Token: %s", apiCaller.token);
                context.done(new Error("Something went wrong with the token. Wrong token!"));
            }
            console.log(str);
            console.log(apiCaller.token);
            TheCallback.apply(context, arguments);
        });
```

**UPDATE:**

By using `call`, `apply` or `bind`, you can execute a the callback function in the context of your choice. It could be `context` object provided or anything else you needed. If you do not need to change the this binding for the callback execution, call it simply with `TheCallback ()`.

Comment: Why are you using `apply`? Why not call it in `request.end()`?